# Enabling autocomplete for .API files?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, notepad++, autocomplete

Does anyone know how to get auto-complete working in Notepad++ using the .API files provided on the N++ site? Autocomplete works fine for me in languages which have an XML autocomplete file in the APIs folder, but completely non-functional for languages that use a .API file (ruby, AutoIt, others).

From what I've been able to find online, all one needs to do is copy the .API or .XML file into the APIs folder, and make sure that the filename matches the language name in the language menu. I quit N++ to make sure it isn't a matter of a refresh happening on start-up.

Per the N++ site, I copied Ruby.apt and AHK Autohotkey.api files into the APIs folder:

C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\APIs

I'm running the newest Notepad++, v5.4.3.  Tried it in Notepad++ 5.3.x on three machines before upgrading.

Answer (score 5):

Just use this one. Name it ruby.xml and place it in the plugins\APIs Folder

[Notepad++ Ruby API XML File](http://pastebin.com/f4fedbb27)

I made it from the ruby.api file. But I guess it's not complete in regrad to the ruby standard library