# unterminated string meets end of file when rendering js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error in my js.erb view :

> unterminated string meets end of file

And I don't know why, it was working before and then it stops.
So, first, i'm calling my controller action through a form with remote => true.

```
<%= form_tag('movers/d/folders', :remote => true) do%>
  my form 
<% end %>
```

Then in my controller action, I'm doing stuff with what the user types in the form.
In my controller action, i'm setting 3 classes variables that I can access from my view.
And then i'm rendering my js.erb view.
Here's my code in this js.erb view :

```
<% @pictures.each do |pic| %><
  alert('<%= pic %>');  
<% end %>
```

Is this correct ? Am I doing stuff right or not ? 
So when i'm running this, i'm getting the unterminated string meets end of file error. I dont understand why I got this.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a single or double quote missing somewhere in the my form that was not posted, without that no one can tell where exactly you are erring, check very well, and do u use an ide or text editor that recognizes the rails/ruby codes you would easily pick this out, just open your eyes wide and you would see it

Comment: Yeah, it was what I was thinking but I wanted to be sure that what I was doing in my view was correct. I'm using Notepad ++ for windows and you're right, I'm sure there is a single or double quote missing somewhere in my code.

Comment: I have used notepad++ for some development on windows, though I 8 windows but have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997011/enabling-autocomplete-in-notepad-for-api-files) should help you with syntax highlighting in notepad++

Comment: Ok I found out the problem, I think the file was corrupted or something like this. I removed it, created a new one and the code above is running. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Two things -- first you have an extraneous '<' at the end of your first line. Second, check out [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript). Try this:

```
<% @pictures.each do |pic| %>
  alert('<%= escape_javascript(pic) %>');    
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think I add the extraneous '<' by mistake when i was writing my question. I tried escape_javascript but i'm still getting the same error. Thanks !